# Error with XmlSerializer on One too Many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

I was given an old Classic Asp application with an Access database to convert to MVC and SQL Server. The tables in the database are mostly unrelated except for two, I've worked around it for now but it will cause problems later.

It all works if I leave the two tables unrelated, it also all works with the tables related when using a 'normal' API but if I try to use the XmlSerializer on any of my Lists, not IList, even the tables that aren't related to these two table at all but are refereced in the same Model, I get this error.

> Cannot serialize member mysite.Models.RunArea.Runs of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[mysite.Models.Run, mysite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

**Update:** I'm on to something, after updating the model from database my RunArea Model now has an ICollection of Runs, what can I do about that?

```
public virtual ICollection<Run> Runs { get; set; }
```

The relationship is One RunArea has many Runs

I have the following code:

**DatabaseFeed Model:**

```
public List<Run> Runs { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Runs()
{
    var runs = db.Runs.ToList();

    DatabaseFeed wf = new DatabaseFeed
    {
        Runs = runs
    };

    XmlSerializer sSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DatabaseFeed));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
    sSubmit.Serialize(xw, wf);
    var xml = sw.ToString();

    return Content(xml, "application/xml");

    /*return View(wf);*/

}
```

This works fine if I remove the relationship between RunArea and Run in the Database and works fine either way if I just **return View(wf);**.

Everything I can find on the net talks about not using IList but i'm not, i'm using a List, so I guess my problem is elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I turned off Lazy Loading, in my Run Model I changed,

```
public virtual RunArea RunAreas { get; set; }
```

to

```
public RunArea RunAreas { get; set; }
```

and in my RunArea Model I changed,

```
public ICollection<Run> Runs { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Run> Runs { get; set; }
```